# ggplot2 geom_col fill giving seemingly random results

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm graphing some data and I want to highlight certain columns based on thresholds but geom_col appears to be assigning colours randomly.

```
dass21_scores_plot %>%    
ggplot(aes(dassId, score, label=score)) 
    + geom_col(fill = 
    ifelse(dass21_scores_plot$score == -1, "blue1", 
        ifelse(dass21_scores_plot$measure == "Depression Baseline" && dass21_scores_plot$score > 27, "red", 
            ifelse(dass21_scores_plot$measure == "Anxiety Baseline" && dass21_scores_plot$score > 19, "red", 
                ifelse(dass21_scores_plot$measure == "Stress Baseline" && dass21_scores_plot$score > 33, "red", "green4")))))
    + geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(score > -1, as.integer(score), ''), vjust = ifelse(score > 21, 2, -1)), size = 4) 
    + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90))
    + facet_wrap(~measure, ncol = 4)
```

This is what I get.

[image]

This doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me as even columns with identical traits are being filled differently. The columns have no attributes that aren't graphed. Is there anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Quick guess: try swapping out all `&&`'s for just `&`. `&` does element-wise comparison, `&&` only looks at the first element of vectors.

Comment: I gave that a go but no change unfortunately.

Comment: (1) Doing complex data manipulations _inside_ a ggplot call is a bad idea; it makes things very hard to debug when things go wrong. (2) You're _setting_ the fill aesthetic, not _mapping_ it inside `aes()`. You'll want to create a new column defining the fill groups ahead of time (don't use the names of the colors). Then map the fill aesthetic to that variable and control the colors with `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: Same thing with the labels; don't do all that manipulation inside the ggplot call. Modify the variable (or create a new one) up front.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using @joran's advice.

Here is my new code:

```
colours <- as.character(c())
for(i in 1:length(dass21_scores_plot$dassId)) {
    x = substr(dass21_scores_plot$measure[i], 1, 3)
    s = dass21_scores_plot$score[i]
    if (s == -1) {
        colours[i] = "b"
    } else if(x == "Dep"){
        colours[i] = ifelse(s >= 28, "r", "g")
    } else if(x == "Anx"){
        colours[i] = ifelse(s >= 20, "r", "g")
    } else if(x == "Str"){
        colours[i] = ifelse(s >= 34, "r", "g")
    }
}
dass21_scores_plot$col <- colours

dass21_scores_plot %>%    
ggplot(aes(dassId, score, label=score)) + geom_col(aes(fill = col), show.legend = F) 
+ geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(score>-1, as.integer(score), ''), vjust = ifelse(score>21, 2, -1)), size=4) 
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90)) + facet_wrap(~measure, ncol=4) 
+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "green4", "red"))
```